# Generated array values changing after While statements

Tags: php

This is a weird issue I have came across and was wondering if anyone my have insight. Not sure if the `mktime` does not function as I am trying to get it to, or what may be going on.

Last night, things were working fine - the months being displayed were correct. Today, though, for some reason the values of my `$aGMonV` are changing somewhere after the `foreach` and before the `while(row_* = mysqli_fetch_array*` statements.

While the var_dump returns `%2014-03%` as the first month (which is correct) - the table that is generated returns `%2013-09%` as the first month. All the queries being ran are being run with `%2013-09%` and NOT starting at current month.

My code is below:

```
$aGMon = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++)
{ $aGMon[] = date('Y-m', mktime(0,0,0,date('n')-$i,1)); }

foreach ($aGMon as $aGMonK => $aGMonV)

{

$aGMonO = $aGMonV;
$aGMonV = " '%" . $aGMonV . "%' ";

$result_E = mysqli_query($con,"select kWh_AVG from UseElecM where Month LIKE " .     $aGMonV . ";");
$result_G = mysqli_query($con,"select TotalMCF from UseGas where Month LIKE " . $aGMonV     . ";");
$result_P = mysqli_query($con,"select (A.Minutes+E.Minutes_L500+E.Minutes_Free) as     Minutes, (A.Texts+E.Texts) as Texts, (A.MMS+E.MMS) as MMS, (A.MBData+E.MBData) as MBData     from UseSprintA A left outer join UseSprintE E on A.Bill = E.Bill where A.Bill     LIKE " . $aGMonV . ";");
$result_T = mysqli_query($con,"select cast((avg(Average)) as decimal (10,1)) as ATF     from CF6MCI where Date LIKE " . $aGMonV . ";");

var_dump($aGMonV);

while($row_E = mysqli_fetch_array($result_E))
while($row_G = mysqli_fetch_array($result_G))
while($row_P = mysqli_fetch_array($result_P))
while($row_T = mysqli_fetch_array($result_T))

{

echo "<td class='UUMonth'>" . ($aGMonO) . "<div class='UUMonthO'>Average temperature: "     . $row_T['ATF'] . " F</div></td>";
echo "<td>" . $row_E['kWh_AVG'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row_G['TotalMCF'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row_P['Minutes'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row_P['Texts'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row_P['MMS'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row_P['MBData'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";

}

}
```

Results of the code are as follows:

[Result of code](http://postimg.org/image/qy8mrn7l3/)

Comment: Do you understand how `while` works? Do you realize what is the statement to loop for the outer `while`?

Comment: I guess I don't follow. I have never had issues with multiple whiles executing properly - I was thinking since the while is in the foreach loop, the foreach loop would loop through each array value, perform the 4 whiles, and then loop to the next array value, so on until it was done looping through the array.

Comment: a hint: every `while` performs independently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user3260912 try removing the while, try like this:

```
$aGMon = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++)
{ $aGMon[] = date('Y-m', mktime(0,0,0,date('n')-$i,1)); }

foreach ($aGMon as $aGMonK => $aGMonV)

{

$aGMonO = $aGMonV;
$aGMonV = " '%" . $aGMonV . "%' ";

$result_E = mysqli_query($con,"select kWh_AVG from UseElecM where Month LIKE " .     $aGMonV . ";");
$result_G = mysqli_query($con,"select TotalMCF from UseGas where Month LIKE " . $aGMonV     . ";");
$result_P = mysqli_query($con,"select (A.Minutes+E.Minutes_L500+E.Minutes_Free) as     Minutes, (A.Texts+E.Texts) as Texts, (A.MMS+E.MMS) as MMS, (A.MBData+E.MBData) as MBData     from UseSprintA A left outer join UseSprintE E on A.Bill = E.Bill where A.Bill     LIKE " . $aGMonV . ";");
$result_T = mysqli_query($con,"select cast((avg(Average)) as decimal (10,1)) as ATF     from CF6MCI where Date LIKE " . $aGMonV . ";");

//var_dump($aGMonV);

$row_E = mysqli_fetch_array($result_E);
$row_G = mysqli_fetch_array($result_G);
$row_P = mysqli_fetch_array($result_P);
$row_T = mysqli_fetch_array($result_T);



echo "<td class='UUMonth'>" . ($aGMonO) . "<div class='UUMonthO'>Average temperature: "     . $row_T['ATF'] . " F</div></td>";
echo "<td>" . $row_E['kWh_AVG'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row_G['TotalMCF'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row_P['Minutes'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row_P['Texts'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row_P['MMS'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row_P['MBData'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";



}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. I'm also going to try joining the queries to return a single result. For the database I have, performance isn't an issue yet.